# Why this error using the javascript split function?

Tags: javascript, split

Using PHP I create a series of a href tags as such;

```
echo ("<a href='#$net[id2]' onclick='putInDebInput(this);'>$net[call] ---> $net[org]</a>");
```

An example of what it creates looks like this;

```
<a href="#3:2:19:CARROLL" onclick="putInDebInput(this);">CARROLL ---&gt; Carroll County MO. ARES</a>
```

When one of them is clicked the putInDebInput() is run. It looks like this;

```
function putInDebInput(pidi) {
    alert(pidi); 
    var pidi2 = pidi.split(":")[4]; 
}
```

The alert returns;

> https://mystuff.us/indexTest.php#19:2:28:CARROLL

But the var `pidi2 = pidi.split(":")[4];` returns this error;

```
TypeError: pidi.split is not a function. (In 'pidi.split(":")', 'pidi.split' is undefined)
```

I'm not seeing the error in my code, so how can the split be "undefined"?

Comment: What do you want the `pid2` variable to contain, given this example input?

Comment: Can you clarify what your expected output is? Best not to immediately go AFK after asking a question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do this:

`onclick="putInDebInput(this);`

You are calling your `putInDebInput` passing the HTML Element and not a string. I believe you wanted to pass the `href` attribute.

You can update your function to something like this:

```
function putInDebInput(pidi) {
   var hrefContent = pidi.getAttribute("href");
   alert(hrefContent);
   var pidi2 = hrefContent.split(":")[3]; // chaged to 3 from 4
}
```

Comment: Yeah, good point. I think the main issue though was about getting the HREF string instead of the actual element.
Thanks for the edit @Keith :)